# How can I get rid of / hide :2eDS_Store files on my linux netatalk server?

Tags: linux, netatalk

I'm running a netatalk server process on my linux server that serves files up to Mac client machines.  Whenever you use Mac's Finder to access foreign filesystems over netatalk, it creates '.DS_Store' files to store information about the folder.

Normally, these files would be hidden by default, and I wouldn't care.  Unfortunately, netatalk doesn't allow access to local hidden files, so when the Mac writes and reads these, it renames them :2eDS_Store on the local filesystem.  When you have a deep tree, you end up with these littered all over the place, and other Windows and Linux clients have to deal with them.

How do I make these available to Mac clients and hidden from everyone else?

Comment: Has your question been answered here or somewhere else?  How about marking an answer...

Comment: It wasn't answered until just now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each share in `/etc/netatalk/AppleVolumes.default` add `options:usedots` to make Netatalk create .DS_Store instead of :2eDS_Store.  The files will still be there, but as dot-files they'll be invisible.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing...

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to use [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) or [BlueHarvest](http://zeroonetwenty.com/blueharvest/) on each Mac to disable the creation of .DS_Store files on non-local disks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a guide on how to disable it's creation on Macintosh based clients: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1629 (With out third party tools)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this one. (just brainstorming)

However, does anyone know whether unionfs can do the trick?

I mean, could we write those files to a specific tree? Where Linux and Windows clients would not see them.

Regards Mike
[;-)